# Load text from file & display in marquee (php & html)

Tags: php, html, marquee

I need to load text from a .txt file and display it on a marquee so when I change what it displays I don't have to go and change all of the pages.

Here's my code:

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><?php include('../Files/marquee/Main_Marquee.txt'); ?></marquee>
```

The text loads and that's it.

This screenshot is the where I'm loading the text from a file. 
http://prntscr.com/7ysws3

And this is the one where I manually enter the text into the document.
http://prntscr.com/7ysxc9

Thanks
-Adam

Comment: `<marquee>` doesn't work in FF anymore, should that be the browser you're using and being the latest version. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee - but this wiki should be updated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element *"and is still supported by it. Firefox..."* - No way José; not in the past latest revisions.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: You're welcome Adam. However, I find it rather strange that what you accepted below, worked for you, rather than a straight include. I tested your code and it worked fine. Could be something rather bizarre happening and will be rather difficult to pinpoint its exact cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left"><?php echo file_get_contents('../Files/marquee/Main_Marquee.txt'); ?></marquee>
```

Comment: I've done "include" in the past with when a site of someone was using `<marquee>` so I can't see how using `file_get_contents()` would make a difference. Plus, I tested OP's code on an older browser and there's no problem.

Comment: well, OP accepted it but I can't see why their code didn't work in the first place and being most bizarre.

Comment: That's because it's text file and It's only included and not displaying or echoing anything that;s why it is not displaying output. `file_get_contents()` will read file and send output with echo.

Comment: I think it may be a browser issue here and or how their system is setup. I tested their code as is, and it worked fine. So this one will remain unresolved for me anyway. OP got their solution and that's what counts.